# HTML page overflows, but can't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to update my website, but the content is overflowing off the screen and going out of view since there's no scroll bar. You can see at [caves.neocities.org](http://caves.neocities.org).

I tried using `margin` and `padding` in the CSS style for the `body` but nothing is working.

Here's the CSS for the `body` and page. The `div`s on my site are all about the same and the HTML for the `div` overflowing is like this:

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-family: Courier;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000000, #435454);
  border: double;
  border-color: #D2EFEF;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="browse">
  <center> Site Links </center> <br>
  <hr> testing, once again!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error :::

.weather class from weather.min.css is overridiing your css rules;

```
.weather {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try this :::

```
body {
    color: black;
    font-family: Courier;
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: it works, i can scroll now. but now there's a LOT of extra space height-wise on the page. how would i make the page less long, just still long enough to keep fitting the content?

Comment: Adjust your .weather class ::after,::before bottom size.

Answer (score 0):

.weather class from weather.css is overridiing your css rules, apply !important on your overflow rule.

Comment: thanks! i'm new to CSS/HTML and didn't know this was a thing. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.weather {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Or

```
body {
    color: black;
    font-family: Courier;
    overflow-y: scroll!important;
}
```